# What types of boarding pass barcodes are accepted at Swedavia airports?

Tags: tickets, mobile-apps, arn, swedavia

I recently downloaded a boarding pass wallet to my phone and it's able to generate 4 different types of barcodes, the normal Aztek and PDF417 but also QR and Data Matrix.

I know that Aztek and PDF417 are supported but I don't ktow about QR and Data Matrix.

Which of these are supported at Stockholm Arlanda Airport?

---

*Swedavia is the government owned company that owns and operates most airports in Sweden.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used all mentioned barcode types with success at ARN:

- PDF417 (normal paper pass)
- Aztec (normal mobile pass)
- Data Matrix
- QR

Airports where mobile boarding passes can be used (IATA BCBP) should support all of these types - it's up to the airline to decide which type they want to use and the data is the same for all types.

It seems all of these are accepted at all Swedavia (government owned) airports in Sweden as the airport use the same types of gates and barcode readers. I've tried them all in a few Swedavia airports now.